# Stripe API - Pull Structured Data in Node.js

Tags: api, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

I’ve just got into the Stripe API and I’m creating an application that will help users view some of their Stripe metrics in a custom dashboard. I’ve created a Connect account and have successfully authenticated users. Now I'm trying to run an initial function to store billing data in my Firebase Firestore database with a format of every day of the companies history with some basic data.

Here is an example of how I'd like to store the data...

```
/companies/{companyId}/stripe
    /2021-06-26
      {
        customers: 12
        revenue: 10499
      }
    /2021-06-25
      {
        customers: 2
        revenue: 1299
      }
    /2021-06-24
      {
        customers: 0
        revenue: 0
      }
```

I want to use this data in a chart so it’s important to show the aggregate numbers by date and also show dates when users don’t have customers/charges. I’ve been playing around with how to write this function to format the data and was wondering if there was an easier way.

Is this something I could use reports for to structure the data first by date? Or should I do something like trying to pull all customers and all charges and add them into an array of dates for uploading?

Comment: Do you need the report for each company separated or do you want an admin like report for all of the users/companies together?

Comment: Each company separate to store in their own `/stripe` collection

Comment: What I can recomment is not to use a  date as key in the collection. Just add the date value in a field. You can query on it later but you would be more flexible with real `id`s